# Dual functor and homology of projective modules

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, algebraic-topology, commutative-algebra, homology-cohomology

Let $$P_1\xrightarrow{f} P_2\xrightarrow{g} P_3$$ be a complex of projective modules over a ring $A$ (We assume that $gf=0$) and let $H=\frac{Ker g}{Im f}$ be a projective module. Let $-^*=Hom(-,A)$ stand for the dual functor and let $$P_3^*\xrightarrow{g^*} P_2^*\xrightarrow{f^*} P_1^*$$ be the dual complex.  Is it true that $\frac{Ker f^*}{Im g^*}=H^*$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no. $\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb Z}\newcommand{\im}{\mathrm{Im}\,}$

take $P_1=0,\,$  $P_2=P_3=\Z\,$  and $g:P_2\to P_3,x\mapsto2x.\,\,$ 
we have $H^*=H=0\,$ because $\ker g=0,\,$ but $\frac{\ker f^*}{\im g^*}=\Z/2\Z\,$  since $g^*(y)=2y$.

in fact, any projective resolution computing nontrivial [ext](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext_functor) gives a counterexample, this is a usual thing in homological algebra.